# Codeigniter3 - Obtener datos desde un controlador enviando un id con ajax

Tags: ajax, json, select, codeigniter-3

he estado revisando el sitio y no he podido encontrar una respuesta a mi duda.
Estoy intentado desde un select con un listado de productos que tengo en una vista que al selecciona uno se me actualicen los datos de existencia de ese producto que obtengo desde una función del controlador. Se como obtenerlos con php, lo que necesito es lograrlo en la misma pagina, sin recargarla, pero no soy muy ducho en javascript y estoy algo perdido.
Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Delvis, considera incluir un [mcve], para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Si no tienes uno, considera repasar un poco de AJAX y despues plantea tus dudas en este sitio.

Comment: lo que he podido hacer hasta ahora es :<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('product_id'){
        if(id) {
            $.ajax({
                  url:"<?=site_url("storemov/getID/$row->product_id")?>",
                  type:"POST",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success:function(respuesta){
                      window.location.href = "<?=site_url("storemov/create/$row->product_id")?>";
                  }
            });
        }
    }
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu vista puedes agregar un script y por javascript obtienes el valor ya sea con un `document.getElementById('tu_selector')` luego de esto envías tu id por ajax al controlador, y la respuesta en el .done te encarga de adaptarla sin necesidad de haber hecho un reload de la página ni submit o algo por el estilo.

> Invocar el elemento JS

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <script>
$(document).on('ready',function(){   
$('#mi_selector').on('change', function() {
              // Para determinar el cambio de valor
    var id = $('#mi_selector).val();
    //alert(id);
              $.ajax({                        
               type: "POST",                 
               url: "mi_controlador", //recordar sin el .php                    
               data: id, 
               success: function(data)             
               {
                 $('#resp').html(data);               
               }
           });
            });
});
</script>
```

luego en tu controlador vas a recibir es la variable y hacer con él lo que deseas para retornar una respuesta.

```
$id = $_POST['data'];
```

Comment: Por lo que he leído eso es exactamente lo que debo hacer pero no se crear el script. he visto varios y he intentado modificarlos pero mi conocimiento es casi nulo en javascript.

Comment: descomente el alert, para confirmar que estoy recibiendo el id pero no me envia nada. #mi_selector es el id="mi_selector" del select no???

Comment: Claro, debes colocar el id de tu select

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Producto</label>
                            <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="mi_selector" name="product_id">
                                <?php foreach ($product->result() as $row): ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$row->product_id?>" ><?=$row->product_code?> - <?=$row->product_name?></option> 
                                <?php  endforeach;?>
                            </select>  
                        </div>

Comment: disculpa es que no se tampoco como escribir codigo aca que me quede organizado.

Comment: ¿Invocaste el script de jquery en tu footer?, colocaste en etiquetas <script></script> aparte al código que te incluí?

Comment: la invocacion de jquery esta en en el header y me funciona porque estan funcionando otros script de la plantilla que lo necesitan. y si agrege las etiquetas <script></script>

Comment: edité mi respuesta a ver si te funciona, Verifica que en el alert está tomando el valor al hacer change en el select

Comment: Ya muestra el alert con la informacion correcta. Ahora en url: "mi_controlador", //recordar sin el .php    debo agregar el contrlador/funcion que quiero enviarle el data no???

Comment: Por favor, si te sirvió la respuesta, márcala como la correcta. En caso tal, sigue indicando cómo se comporta para poder ayudar en la resolución de tu caso.

Comment: Excelente @DelvisDíaz. Y sí, procede a enviar en la url tu controlador/función a la cual deseas enviar el parámetro. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta al lograr tu objetivo.

Comment: veo por consola que llega hasta el metodo. el metodo es public function getData(){

     $id = $_POST['data'];
     $data['query'] = $this->storeproducts_model->get_product_by_id($id);
     $this->load->view('store/product/ajaxx', $data);
    
   } donde ajaxx es una vista que cree para que me mueste uno de los datos obtenidos, pero esa vista no se ve. Disculpa tanta molestia

Comment: Claro ahora en la respuesta obtenida debes montar en un div con un id tu vista. Recuerda que invocas un elemento html y debes buscar encajarlo en tu vista principal para que no te recargue

Answer (score 0):

Lo que he podido hacer hasta ahora es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('product_id'){
        if(id) {
            $.ajax({
                  url:"<?=site_url("storemov/getID/$row->product_id")?>",
                  type:"POST",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success:function(respuesta){
                      window.location.href = "<?=site_url("storemov/create/$row->product_id")?>";
                  }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Donde `('product_id')` es mi select, 
`storemov/getID/$row->product_id` es la llamada al método que me filtra la consulta,
es la pagina que debería recargar